# Send file via POST using Mootools or JQuery

Tags: jquery, post, mootools

i want to know if i can send a file (image or document) using an HTTPRequest, how do i have to code the file?

Comment: Do you want to POST the file via AJAX?  'how do i have to code the file'  Code what file?  Please add more details.

Comment: sorry, my mistake... i am usign PHP, and usually when i send a form, the data travels via $_POST and the files via $_FILES, so i mean to translate (code) the files.data into post.data

Comment: Why do you want to send a file via `$_POST` instead of `$_FILES`?

Comment: it's a form to update the photo of a user, and i would like to use AJAX

Comment: it's not possible to AJAX a file upload in the _normal_ sense (sending a form). there is AIM (Ajax iframe method). then, there are various flash-based uploaders like digitarald's fancy upload (for mootools that is). then, there's HTML5 like this https://developer.mozilla.org/en/using_files_from_web_applications - used in mootools plugins like http://mootools.net/forge/p/uploadmanager - that use progressive enhancement to try all 3 methods until one works. good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Use a form on a webpage:

http://cgi-lib.berkeley.edu/ex/fup.html

Your browser creates the HTTPRequest and POSTs it to server that you set in the action attribute of the form element.